# Jquery hide\show functionality

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have a table implemented using JQuery. Requirement is to have a View link, when the user clicks on it..the table should be shown. And a hide\close link which will hide the displayed table.

Thank You.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Code?

Comment: check jQuery docs for show / hide methods. There are plenty of samples in internet

Comment: i dont know how to do it. I did hide it using hide().var childT = $('<table class="standard"/>').appendTo(td).hide();

Comment: in such cases, you should always post your code which is not working.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily do it by adding toggle event on link click

```
   $('#lnkVisible').click(function(){
        $('.standard').toggle();
    });​
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d6n6m/1/)

Mark this as answer if it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can try .toggle() function.
See more [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0):

Give id to your table as "mytable" and put this as your js

```
$('#Link').click(function(){
    $('#mytable').toggle();
});​
```

that's it.You can also use FadeIn,FadeOut for more effects.
In individual

```
$('#Display_Link').click(function(){
    $('#mytable').show();
});
$('#Hide_Link').click(function(){
    $('#mytable').hide();
})
```